# Authenticating users to a web page while preventing them to access it via direct links

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, authentication

I'm working on a web page that connects to some databases and I need to make sure only the right people get access to edit it. Right now it has authentication using Microsoft Office 365, but people can still get around it by writing the direct link to the page. I want to make users log in, like social networks, where it creates a session and even though you can copy paste the link, it wont work on other computers. Some websites create url's ending in things like /auth=2 or something and if you log out and go to that link, it doesn't work. That's what I want in my page, just like the major social networks. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm currently developing the website in ASP.NET MVC with C#, HTML, and working it on Visual Studio 2017.

Thank you!!

Comment: If you use MVC then just add `[Authorize]` attribute to the page controller.

Comment: Go through this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

Comment: Sorry for replying a year after, got back to working on the project recently. The [Authorize] attribute was the perfect solution, thank you very much!